# Which Windows Server License would be most cost effective?

Tags: windows-server, asp.net

I am running a Microsoft Azure instance for hosting ASP.NET websites and a Teamspeak server. For my needs, the price is fairly expensive, so I'm looking for a self-hosted solution.

My requirements for my machine are:

- 5+ user license
- 1 physical CPU support (8 logical cores)
- 16 GB RAM support
- virtualization support
- hosting of ASP.NET websites
- hosting a Teamspeak server
- running Node.JS applications
- cost less than an Azure A2 basic tier instance ($60 per month), a one-time perpetual license is preferred

I don't need:

- MS SQL Server
- hosting (since that's off-topic for this site)

Comment: So if I simply add to my question my requirements, then would the question be valid?

Comment: Basically yes: define your needs, e.g. how many users, how many CPUs etc. I'm uncertain whether we recommend licenses, though. IMHO this has not been discussed on Meta yet. Give it a try and perhaps that'll result in a discussion. I'd not be too specific about Windows Server 2012. Maybe you'll find out that Windows Home Server or Windows Server 2015 fits even better.

Comment: Edited some more, it's correct.

Comment: Although it's been edited so heavily there is hardly a question anymore, I need to know which specific license to get.  Is this question okay?

Comment: IMHO it's ok and I left a chat message for the moderators to reopen. This might take a while, since we don't have so many users here. Just wait a bit. Let's see what you get as answers. Maybe there's an even better answer than a Windows Server license.

Comment: For a Windows license recommendation we'd also need to know if the website serves pages that are only accessible after user login (which requires CALs) or if you have anonymous public content only (does not require CALs)

Comment: No I would not need that sort of Client Access License.  This is primarily a production server in which only about 3 programmers would need access to.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you only need CALs if you are using Windows authentication if you are using forms authentication then you do not need CALs

Comment: @AidenGrossman: are you sure? You even need CALs for getting an IP address via DHCP... In any case, what OP describes seems not need more than the 5 CALs that are included in the Standard Edition.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if you have a sql server then you do need a CAL but if you are running logins off of something such as MySQL or an xml file you do not need a CAL for that

Comment: The OP started a discussion whether [license questions are on-topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/should-software-and-os-license-comparison-questions-be-off-topic) on Meta.

Comment: I am certain my requirements do not need more than 5 CALs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can say, a **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard** license + **5 user CALs** are required here.

- **cost less than an Azure A2 instance**: The cost is ~630 EUR ([Reichelt, German](http://www.reichelt.de/WINS2012-R2-STD/3/index.html?&ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=154336&artnr=WINS2012+R2+STD), at the time of writing).

  Given you can buy hosting for ~25 EUR/mon ([netcup](https://www.netcup.de/vserver/), RS 4000 G7 at the time of writing), that saves you ~35 EUR/mon, which means you need to run it for 18 months to become more cost effective than your Azure instance.

  That said, be aware that Windows Server 2016 will come soon. Perhaps you want to wait for that version to have longer support.
- **5+ user license**: CALs are no longer included, so you need to buy them on top. A 5 user CAL is at ~170 EUR (Reichelt, German).

  This decreases the ROI from 18 months to 22 months.

  I trust the comment of [@Aiden Grossman](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/15684/aiden-grossman) here, who said:

  > you only need CALs if you are using Windows authentication if you are using forms authentication then you do not need CALs

  and I'm assuming that you're doing your own user management and not use Active Directory to manage users. My reasoning is as follows:

  If you do form-based authentication using MS SQL Server, no Windows Server CAL is needed, but you need a SQL Server CAL. Now, remove the SQL Server and replace by mySQL.
- **1 physical CPU support**: support for 2 CPUs,  (8 logical cores??)
- **16 GB RAM support**: [4 TB supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2012)
- **virtualization support**: included for 2 VMs (you can see that in the technical data at Reichelt)
- **hosting of ASP.NET websites**: comes with IIS
- **hosting a Teamspeak server**: ok, it's free AFAIK, not part of the question
- **running Node.JS applications**: ok, it's free AFAIK, not part of the question

Comment: According to this article Windows Server 2016 is releasing in September 2016 (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/07/windows-server-2016-coming-in-september-with-new-servicing-for-nano-server/), so thanks for the tip and the response.